# Is there any other way to get metal scraps other than a crowbar in H1Z1?

Tags: h1z1-just-survive

I have been trying the Alpha and was wondering if anyone had found any way to get metal scrap other than the crowbar? I see lots of things being constructed, but I have not found any way to get the tool needed to farm the parts.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Crowbar is the only way to create Metal Scrap, however, Metal Scrap also spawns in vehicles and some containers.